# Will the time for seeking an operation in relational db will be solved with the advent of ssd's?

Tags: sql, database, join

I understand that relational databases store data in HDD's and there the main concern for query optimization is the way HDD's work i.e the seek time required for the spindle to reach the location from where it starts reading data. 
Reading about SSD's I figured they are very fast in seeking the data, so is it safe to assume the join operation between different tables which use to take a lot of time and because of which we denormalize the table will be solved?

Also, will B-trees and other Data Structures will become obsolete in DB read/write?

Comment: It’s not that simple. A lot of the data is in memory, caches, and it all depends on data, structure, queries and whatnot. Not all data is on HDDs and the main concern often is not data access. Other things may change performance a lot before we even consider accessing anything.

Comment: SSDs are faster than HDDs.  That can solve some problems, but your problem is quite unclear.